# JavaFx msal4j NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, javafx, azure-ad-msal

I am running into an exception trying to get the example code [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/wiki/Acquiring-Token-Interactively) working with a JavaFx desktop app.

Java Version - OpenJDK 17
OS - Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa

My Azure app reg has been setup,

```
private String PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID = "my client id from azure";
private String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/";
```

My code is setup inside my Controller's constructor

```
    public HelloController() throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException {
        PublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplication
                .builder(PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID)
                .authority(AUTHORITY)
                .build();

        InteractiveRequestParameters parameters = InteractiveRequestParameters
                .builder(new URI("http://localhost"))
                .scopes(Collections.singleton("user.read"))
                .build();

        IAuthenticationResult result = app.acquireToken(parameters).join();

    }
```

And gets this stack trace upon startup complaining about not being able to find com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpHandler

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/chewy/IdeaProjects/FxTimer/target/classes/com/example/fxtimer/hello-view.fxml:23

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:944)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:981)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:755)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at com.example.fxtimer/com.example.fxtimer.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:290)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:939)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpHandler
    at msal4j@1.11.2/com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase.getAuthenticationResultSupplier(AbstractClientApplicationBase.java:145)
    at msal4j@1.11.2/com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase.executeRequest(AbstractClientApplicationBase.java:117)
    at msal4j@1.11.2/com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.PublicClientApplication.acquireToken(PublicClientApplication.java:115)
    at com.example.fxtimer/com.example.fxtimer.HelloController.<init>(HelloController.java:112)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 27 more
Exception running application com.example.fxtimer.HelloApplication

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I do add that httpserver as a dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.net.httpserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>http</artifactId>
            <version>20070405</version>
        </dependency>
```

I get a little further until something else is undefined. No browser window ever launches.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/chewy/IdeaProjects/FxTimer/target/classes/com/example/fxtimer/hello-view.fxml:23

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:944)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:981)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:755)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at com.example.fxtimer/com.example.fxtimer.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:290)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:939)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/ServiceConfigurationError
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1770)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1760)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/ServiceConfigurationError
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:110)
    at msal4j@1.11.2/com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.HttpListener.startListener(HttpListener.java:19)
    at msal4j@1.11.2/com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.startHttpListener(AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.java:90)
    at msal4j@1.11.2/com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.getAuthorizationResult(AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.java:55)
    at msal4j@1.11.2/com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByInteractiveFlowSupplier.java:37)
    at msal4j@1.11.2/com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:71)
    at msal4j@1.11.2/com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:20)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 14 more
Exception running application com.example.fxtimer.HelloApplication

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone know what is causing this Class definitions to be missing/what I need to do in order to get everything working nicely?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'll definitely try to get an MRE setup as an example, my javafx app does have a module-info.java file and by adding requires jdk.httpserver I am able to get past the errors - sadly it looks like the app.acquireToken thread never joins back to the main thread (no browser window ever opens)

Comment: "sadly it looks like the app.acquireToken thread never joins back to the main thread (no browser window ever opens)" -> this appears to be a separate issue exposed by addressing the modular requirement issue.  You could ask a new question about that with an [mcve] and perhaps file another issue with Microsoft if warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add a dependency for the http server, it is [in the jdk](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.httpserver/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html).

Perhaps you need to [require it as a module](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Asker confirmed this worked in comments:

> my javafx app does have a module-info.java file and by adding requires jdk.httpserver I am able to get past the errors

The Microsoft library should define a module-info.java file which appropriately defines the module and its requirements; however, it does not do so. Log a bug report in their issue tracker. You might be able to get it to work in a modular environment by some hacks or VM arguments or running stuff off the class path instead.

Try to replicate this behavior in a modular Java app (app with module-info.java), which does not use JavaFX, to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit the question to include your example and also put the example in your issue report to Microsoft.

Asker also did this, as confirmed in comments, see the issue report at:

- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/issues/473

---

The second exception you posted,

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError
```

is because `sun.misc` APIs were never part of the public JRE API and several `sun.misc` APIs (including this one) were deprecated in JDK 9 and removed from the JDK as part of the modularity work.

The exception occurred because you tried to bring in a really old dependency on a 2007 version of the `com.sun.net.httpserver` API which is not compatible with Java 9+.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help, I've posted an issue on their github that will probably be helpful for anyone seeing this later as well https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/issues/473